# PHP json_decode returns null, even though the json is valid

Tags: php, json, webhooks

```
<?php

    require_once('config.php'); //connection info

    $array = array();
    // var_dump($array);

    $json = file_get_contents("php://input");

    if (empty($json)){
        //theres no data; do nothing
        // $file = fopen("log.txt","a");
        // fwrite($file, "no data");
        // fclose($file);
    } else {
        //using a file because json_decode doesn't work from what ever data is being pulled from the webhook

        $myfile = fopen("log.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!"); 
        //open file for writing. use w so that it erases old data every time before it adds new data

        // $data =  fread($myfile,filesize("logs.txt"));
        // fwrite($myfile, $json);

        // This will remove unwanted characters.
        // Check http://www.php.net/chr for details

        for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; ++$i) { 
            $json = str_replace(chr($i), "", $json); 
        }
        $json = str_replace(chr(127), "", $json);

        // This is the most common part
        // Some file begins with 'efbbbf' to mark the beginning of the file. (binary level)
        // here we detect it and we remove it, basically it's the first 3 characters 
        if (0 === strpos(bin2hex($json), 'efbbbf')) {
           $json = substr($json, 3);
        }

        fwrite($myfile, $json); //write the stripped version of the json
        $data = json_decode($json, true);
        fwrite($myfile, print_r($data, true));

        // print_r($json);
        array_push($array, $data); //add data to array variable. This is not neccesary, but it was used during testing phase.

        $url = /*"http://localhost:5984/incoming";*/"https://gel.freshservice.com"; //this is the response url

        switch (json_last_error()) { //this was for testing the json data from freshservice
            case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
                echo ' - No errors';
                fwrite($myfile, ' - No errors');
            break;
            case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
                echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
                fwrite($myfile, ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded');
            break;
            case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
                echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
                fwrite($myfile, ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch');
            break;
            case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
                echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
                fwrite($myfile, ' - Unexpected control character found');
            break;
            case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
                echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
                fwrite($myfile, ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON');
            break;
            case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
                echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
                fwrite($myfile, ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded');
            break;
            default:
                echo ' - Unknown error';
                fwrite($myfile, ' - Unknown error');
            break;
        }

        $meta = ["received" => time(),
        "status" => "new",
        "agent" => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']];

        $options = ["http" => [
        "method" => "POST",
        "header" => ["Content-Type: application/json"],
        "content" => json_encode(["data" => $data, "meta" => $meta])]
        ];

        $context = stream_context_create($options);
        $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context); //http_response_code()

        //Do something with the array now
?>
```

If I create a random php that reads the txt file and use `json_decode` on the data in the file, this works fine, but once I use `php://input`, it returns `NULL`. Also `json_last_error()` returns no errors.

Comment: Post a view source copy of the page with a `echo $json;`

Comment: whats the content of php://input?

Comment: If the JSON is valid, why do you have to do all that fiddling with it?

Comment: Also why is your `json_last_error()` testing so far after the actual `json_decode()`

Comment: `json_last_error()` will return nothing, if nothing was given to `json_decode()`. So the issue is that reading `php://input` is not where your json is coming in from.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. I'm honestly not sure what I changed, but now it works as it should. Thank you and sorry for consuming your time.

Answer (score 0):

How are you feeding data to the php script?

The only thing that I see is that you're missing a closing curly brace }
at the end to close your `else` case for `if (empty($json))`.
(After `//Do something with the array now`)

After I added the curly brace the code works for me, as far as I can tell. (Log gets written, etc)

Comment: That must be a copying error or the code wouldn't even run, so it couldn't return `null`.

Comment: That was my thought, although I've tested the code. And it runs "correctly" (as far as I can tell,  the var_dump() is producing a decoded json structure). 
I don't have the include for the connection settings, and I don't know if there is something wrong with the input data from the client or if some server configuration is hindering the script from executing correctly for OP.